# AS2: error using .createTextField()

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to index a simple 2D coordinate system with numbers. So I have to add mutiple TextFields. I tryed like this:

```
for (var i = 1;i<4;i++){
display.createTextField("x_"+i, 1, (10*i)+5, 0, 10, 20);
eval("display.x_"+i).text = i;
eval("display.x_"+i).textColor = 0x000000;
}
```

But this only output the last Number(in this case **3**), but why?
I am prohibited to use ActionScript 3, because we only work with Macromedia Flash 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still try to strong type variables in actionscript 2.
Also, you can store the new text field in a variable to avoid using `eval()`.

The other problem is that you are using a constant(1) as the second parameter to the `createTextField()` function. This means you will create only a single text field in the end: the last one, which is why you see 3. 
Because all 3 text fields are on the same depth in the same movieclip, the most recently added replaces the previous one:

```
    for (var i:Number = 1; i < 4; i++){
       var textField:TextField = display.createTextField("x_"+i, i, (10*i)+5, 0, 10, 20);
       textField.text = i.toString();
    }
```

Notice `i` is passed as the second parameter, not `1`.

Additionally, you can store these in an array for later use if that's helpful:

```
var textFields:Array = [];
for (var i:Number = 1; i < 4; i++){
   textFields[i] = display.createTextField("x_"+i, i, (10*i)+5, 0, 10, 20);
   textFields[i].text = i;
}
```

(According to the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001286.html), the default textColor is 0x000000)

Comment: This is totes correct. Also, it is good practice to store your dynamically-created objects in arrays, since in AS3 you can run into problems when creating  objects within a loop.

`for(var zz:int =0;zz<objCount;zz++){

 `   var myDynamicObject:DynamicObjectType = new      `DynamicObject([params]);
`     addChild(myDynamicObject);

`}

This will usually end placing one object on your display list(if any), since the object will be reset with each loop.  Instead you want to add the object to an array.  I know you're in AS2, but it's still good practice, since you can easily call funcs on the objs